# Magento 2 - Order overview open how to open in a new window/tab

Tags: magento2, admin

I've searched and searched.

What i'd like to achieve is from the order overview that the PDF is opened in a new window/tab.

Go to: Sales - Order in the admin
Select a order (Using the checkbox in the first column)
Select print invoices from the Actions dropdown menu.

Result is in the current window the invoices PDF. How can I change this to be in a new window/tab.

I think I need to make a change in the source code.
I've searched on the file system, no solution found using search so far.

Comment: You mean to open the invoice pdf in new tab? Currently magento downloads the pdfs when you click print. Do you want to open those in new window?

Comment: Yes, default chrome-settings is to open a PDF in the browser, I want to force Magento (2.2.3) to make this request to a new window, the current order overview page is available for the user, and the PDF is available in a new window  for the user. (I altered the chrome settings so the PDF is downloaded, but this is still an extra user action)

Comment: Anyone with a solution?

Comment: Anyone have this solution ?

Comment: @arjentuin Does Anyone have the solution